# How to fix the cordova builds issue when we updated from cordova 5.1 version to cordova 9.0.0 version

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

Previously my cordova version was 5.1.1 and it was working fine.
For adding `fileopener2` plugin, I updated my cordova version to 9.0.0.

For the debug apk it is working fine with cordova 9.0.0, but when I am signing the application in eclipse and running the generated signed apk the application is crashing.

I observed during the signing the application in eclipse, that some files are not loading and not updating like build directory and plugins in the src directory which were previously loaded for cordova 5.1.1.

Can any one please help. I am struggling since one week.